# Core data query on a NSSet of NSSet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, core-data

I'm struggling with core data... I don't understand some things so if someone could help me, I would be very grateful!
I have an entity (Recipe) with a relationship to-many with another one (Meal). I would like to select all the recipes which have no connection with a meal... so I've tried:

Code:

[myRecipes filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"meal=%@", nil]];

But it doesn't work... it crashes.

When I look at the SQL database under recipe I don't see meal (I think it's because it's a to-many relationship). How can I make it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164338/core-data-nspredicate-and-to-many-key)

> To test for an empty relationship you should compare the count of the to-many key to zero.

For example,

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"meal.@count == 0"]
```