# Core Data Test Existence of Relationship

Tags: iphone, core-data

I've found various ways [including this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164338/core-data-nspredicate-and-to-many-key) to test for the existence of to many relationships. What I want to know though is how to test for the non-existence of a one way relationship. Here's what I've come up so far:

> NSPredicate *p =
>   [NSPredicate
>   predicateWithFormat:@"category
>   = nil AND (ANY %@ <= created_at) AND (ANY created_at <= %@)", date1, date2];

The previous code will raise this exception:

> The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.

I'm not sure what's wrong here, I just want to fetch records with category nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I'd put the first expression in paranthesis too.

Secondly your exception has nothing to do with checking for a nil value, but (as the exception suggests) with putting `ANY` at the beginning of the other two expressions. You're checking for single dates in both cases, not arrays of dates. Just leave the `ANY`'s out and it should be working as expected.

Just in case date1 and date2 are in fact arrays, you need to use the `%K` placeholder instead of `%@` for dynamic objects.