# keyPath for relationship property count

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to create an NSPredicate for a fetched results controller, the controller should only observe objects that have a relationship (where it's not nil) and where the relationship's count is greater than 0.

I've seen how to do this with a string as the argument of the predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"excludedOccurrences.@count == 0"];
```

from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1195519/4096655

but I am trying to get away from literal strings so I'd like to use a key path.

Example:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class Animal: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var friends: NSSet?
}

let keyPath = #keyPath(Animal.friends.count)
```

results in the error:
Ambiguous reference to member 'count'

Comment: I don't know if there is a better solution, but `NSPredicate(format: "%K.@count = 0", #keyPath(Animal.friends))` could work.

Comment: @MartinR it is a better solution, it causes a compile time error if the property does change, thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`#keyPath` does not know about the `@count` operator. But you can
use it for the "Animal.friends" key path and append `@count`
in the predicate format string:

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K.@count = 0", #keyPath(Animal.friends))
```